# Publishing angular4 app

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular 4 and so I am trying to play a little bit with the framework. I have installed the `angular-cli` and created my project with the commands `ng new MyProject` then inside the /MyProject folder I can work on the files and see the results using `ng serve`.

I tried to compile the app and make it work in a production server (only the sample app angular 4 provides) using the command `ng build --prod` and I see the `/dist` folder and here is my question:

Should I copy all the files inside the `/dist` folder and paste into the public folder in the production server and open index.html?

At this point should I just double click `/dist/index.html` and see the result in a web browser? Because I see a blank page, there is nothing inside `<app-root></app-root>`.

Do I need to do something else? Any help please?

Comment: dist folder should contain everything you need, just make sure you have a webserver running and serving the root of the application

Comment: Also depending on how you serve it, (express, IIS etc..) it will be at a specific path so it may not work just clicking to the index.html

Comment: *Should I double click index.html*: no: that would make the browser open the index.html file from the file system. The URL would be something like `file:///...`. You want to access your webapp over HTTP, so you need to go to the address of your web server. If it runs on your own machine,  `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8080` if the web server runs on port 8080.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an HTTP(or web) server to serve your angular application. And point your server to dist directory(or move your dist folder content to production server default directory).

> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file that it does not have.

Complete deployment example is on angular official site... [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: I got it, I installed a XAMPP server and places the files inside ngproject and compiled the app like this: `ng build --prod --base-href /ngproject` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although you will get a lot of document describing step by step process to build your first angular application. Let me explain from where you stuck or need little bit push.

Should I copy all the files inside the /dist folder and paste into the public folder in the production server and open index.html?

Yes! Its all generated code and cli understand that you are asking the code which you will place in your production server like tomcat or any web server. So you can directly copy it and it will work

As you made a production build, angular did all like minified, moved assets, compiled typescript to javascript etc and did put all them in the dist folder.

If you want to see what is build and is everything fine, you can install `http server` on your machine.Below are the steps.

- install http-server by command `npm i -g http-server`.
- then go to your `/dist` folder and run your generated code in http server by command `http-server` in command prompt.
- Normally it runs at port `8080` so go to `http://localhost:8080` to see your changes.

At this point should I just double click /dist/index.html and see the result in a web browser? Because I see a blank page, there is nothing inside .

You see that because the angular app is not injected when you just open the `index.html`. I think what you want is a development environment. So without building your application, you can run `ng serve` which will run your code in a debug environment and you can see just by going to `http://localhost:4200`.